# Re-installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, reinstall

My dual boot Ubuntu system has its Ubuntu OS corrupted.  Efforts to fix it via changing `source.list` and other means proved in vain.  Now I want to re-install Ubuntu on that partition with a USB stick.  Will my files on that partition and other partitions be left intact?  I just wanna fix the OS.  Wanna confirm this as I am using the computer for many things and cant afford to have it screwed up.  Thanks.

Comment: Before you do **anything** to your OS you should always make sure to have an up-to-date backup of all your personal files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you've set up Ubuntu and what choices you make during the re-installation.

Of course, before going any further, ***back up***!

First, about your current installation...  Ubuntu is installed in the root partition (/).  That partition will be erased.  If your /home partition is separated, then you are fine.  If it is just another directory in /, then yes, that too will be erased.  If you don't know, then run `df -h`.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2          -     -     -   2% /
/dev/sdb1          -     -     -  41% /home
```

This shows that my /home is separate from /.  If /home doesn't appear, then it is part of /, and it will get erased.  This is true for any other partition...  If /etc, /var, etc. do not show up here, then it'll be erased along with /.  You said you can't boot up so you probably cannot run the `df -h` command, but you can use a boot disk and run `gparted` to take a look at how everything is organized.

Anything of value in / that you want, you should use a boot disk and an external drive and copy it out manually.

During installation, you will be presented with the image [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall), under "Installation Type".  You should pick "Something else".  You will then be presented with images similar to those shown [here](https://gparted.org/screenshots.php).  (I can't remember if it uses `gparted` -- I think it does.)  You'll be able to choose which partition is mounted as /, /home, and so far.  The key here is to select your home partition to be mounted as /home but do **not** have it erased.  / will be erased...there's nothing you can do about that.

In summary, you need to be weary of two things:

1. Anything of value to you isn't currently in the root (/) partition.  If it is, use a boot disk and either move it to an external drive or move it to another drive if you have more than one on the computer.  Everything in (/) will be deleted.
2. During installation, carefully select which drives are being erased.  Ubuntu 18.04 no longer has a tmp partition.  If memory serves, this means only two partitions will be marked as reformatted:  (a) the root partition and (b) the EFI system partition which is mounted on /boot/efi .  Anything else won't be erased, provided you are careful and select that option.  (You *can* make a mistake and choose your /home partition to be mounted and erased.)

Hope this helps!  I just had to go through this a month ago...  Re-installation of Ubuntu took less than 15 minutes.  Moving files out of the root partition to a place that won't be erased took well over a day.  But, obviously, such preparation is worth it and I wouldn't rush it...

Good luck!